# How to use for each loop for std::vector<std::string>>?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a for each loop to iterate through a vector of strings, but I keep getting an error that says: 
`expected initializer before ':' token`.
This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
std::vector<std::string> tokens {"Dog","Ship","Coffee","Laptop","Shoe","McDonald's Cup","Airplane","Cellphone"};
int token_num=1;
for (std:string& token : tokens) {
     std::cout<<token_num<<": "<<token<<"\n";
     token_num++;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens {"Dog","Ship","Coffee","Laptop","Shoe","McDonald's Cup","Airplane","Cellphone"};
int token_num=1;
for (const auto& token : tokens) {
     std::cout<<token_num<<": "<<token<<"\n";
     token_num++;
}
```

but I'm getting the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your for loop really outside of any function?

Comment: Range-based loops have only been enabled in C++ 11. How did you compile the code? If you use g++, try adding `-std=c++11`

Comment: also, std:string wouldn't compile.

Comment: Just ensure that c++11 standard is enabled and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing `int main()`
Check this out, this works fine.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<string> tokens {"Dog","Ship","Coffee","Laptop","Shoe","McDonald's Cup","Airplane","Cellphone"};
    int token_num=1;
    for (string& token : tokens) {
         cout<<token_num<<": "<<token<<"\n";
         token_num++;
    }


    token_num=1;
    for (const auto& token : tokens) {
        cout<<token_num<<": "<<token<<"\n";
        token_num++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```